# Jquery Passing this as function parameter

Tags: javascript

### HTML

```
<input type="button" id="1" class="add" value="+" title="Add" onclick="set(this);"/>
```

### JS

```
function set(obj){
   alert(obj.id);
}
```

The above code is not working.

### What I Require

I need to pass the id attribute of the button in the onclick function. Is there any way I could achieve this.

Comment: Works just fine -> http://jsfiddle.net/AfmV9/

Comment: Where is the jQuery in that code?

Comment: @adeneo what do you mean put it after? That does not matter!

Comment: What is NOT working. What happens, is there an error?

Comment: @epascarello - It was just a question, I removed it as I too realized that with just a function it makes no difference where the script is placed. The posted code work fine, something else must be going on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your html should be

```
 <input type="button" id="1" class="add" value="+" title="Add" onclick="set(this.id);"/>
```

and write java script function as

```
function set(id)
   {
   alert(id);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

Your title mentions jQuery, but you're working with a JS solution. If you want to do this with jQuery:

HTML:

```
<input type="button" id="1" class="add" value="+" title="Add" />
```

JS:

```
$("#1").click(function(){alert(this.id);});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fJ5L6/)